# Combining values in certain rows columnwise (in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I do not still grok the right tool for what I need to do in pandas. 
It probably needs groupby(), but I was not able to locate the pythonic way (or any other) in the docs or on the web yet.

I have a table with data of a similar structure (30-50 columns):

```
ID   name  Town     s1       s2       s3       s4

21   Joe   Bonn     rd       fd       NaN      aa
21   Joe   Bonn     NaN      hg       kk       NaN
22   Ann   Oslo     jg       hg       zt       uz
29   Mya   Rome     rd       fd       NaN      aa
```

I would like to combine rows with the same ID (that would be the index), combining the values in the rows without duplication, forming kind of a union of the string values.

So the result would be:

```
21   Joe   Bonn     rd       fd,hg    kk       aa
22   Ann   Oslo     jg       hg       zt       uz
29   Mya   Rome     rd       fd       NaN      aa
```

df.groupby(df.index).sum() was a guess, but it just gives one NaN next to each index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try something as this, you need to drop missing values before using the `join` function:

```
df.groupby(["ID", "name", "Town"], as_index=False).agg(lambda col: ','.join(col.dropna()))

#   ID  name    Town    s1     s2    s3    s4
#0  21   Joe    Bonn    rd  fd,hg    kk    aa
#1  22   Ann    Oslo    jg     hg    zt    uz
#2  29   Mya    Rome    rd     fd          aa
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! At last, this is giving results almost as I intended. I only needed to massage the lambda to avoid duplication:  `lambda col: ','.join(numpy.unique(col.dropna()))`

Comment: Just as a side note, if you want to remove duplicates, you can also use the `drop_duplicates()` without invoking `numpy` explicitly. `lambda col: ','.join(col.dropna().drop_duplicates())`